# Find first peak of sine wave / detect variable change c#

Tags: c#, variables, trigonometry

I am trying to find at what index a sine curve (which may start at any point along the curve) reaches its first maximum, and only the first. To do this, I am running a loop which compares one value to its previous. If one point is greater than its previous value, it is trending up, and similar for the opposite.

In c#, how do you detect when the variable has changed from trending up to trending down? In other words, how do you detect when the variable has changed. In `LabVIEW`, this can be done using a shift register. What is the equivalent in c#?

Comment: What have you come up with so far? There are many ways to do this; it would be useful to know what we can base answers on.

Comment: So far my structure is as follows: pardon my notation.
"

for (i = 1; [end of sine array]
if(sinearray[i] < sinearray[i-1])
{trending = down}
else
{trending = up}

"
If I can find when the "trending" value changes from "Up" to "Down", I can easily find which index this is at. 

I have the "up" value set to 2 and the "down" value set to 1, just for comparison

Edit/disclaimer: I do not know how to make a new line in comments

Comment: You could compute the 1. derivative and look for a change in sign. You probably can do that on-the-fly without having to compute all through the array. Just break the loop on first >0 to <=0 change.

Comment: How would I compute the 1st derivative? In my setup, the curve is actual data received which is generally a sine wave, but does not follow a defined function (due to the fact that it is data). 

Additionally I have thought of another method which may work? Look through the array as previously mentioned, but only when the trend is up, then begin to compare the value for a change. So in simple code: if (trend = up), { if (trend != down) {return the index}}. The only issue with this, is that the trend switches to down, it will not enter the statement to compare.

Comment: isiro's answer should give you a relatively good starting point. Although: I gave this a second thought over night. You would still have to deal with two problems: 1. Start value: What if your first value is already a max? Would you like that one or the next local max? 2. Step width: It could be that the actual function is turning shortly before the second point. Like for example value[n] = 0.5 and value[n+1] = 0.7 but the actual max (1.0) is somewhere in between but closer to n+1. That means computing a trend for n and n+1 in the form of value[n+1]-value[n] would give you a "false up" ...

Comment: Is the sin translated in y-direction? If not, you could detect 0-crossings. If you have those, your mins and maxs are in the middle of those. So you could cut the value array so that values until the 3rd 0-crossing remain and take the max(value[i]) index from those. If it is translated in y, you'd have to compute for how much, translate back and then you could again go about as described first.

Comment: `on hold as too broad`?? OP is asking whether c# has a functionality that apparently labview has / an algorithm for it if not. How is this too broad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int FirstMaxIndex(int[] values)
{
    bool up = false;
    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
        if (values[i] < values[i - 1])
        {
            if (up) return i;
            else up = false;
        }
        else if (values[i] > values[i - 1])
        {
            up = true;
        }
    return -1;
}
```

I didn't test this. This is only to give you an idea of how to solve this. (I wrote it as close as possible to what you wrote in a comment.)

Comment: Downvoter: Care to explain what's wrong with this? It absolutely makes sense ...

Comment: This wouldn't work because it fails to take into account what the original trend of the curve is. If it starts trending down, it will immediately return the first value. I need to find when it changes FROM up to down, not just return when it is down

Comment: @msegctc No it won't. `up` is false to begin with. And `return i;` is only ***if (up)*** (which means: if up is true).

Comment: I apologize, this should work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Two things here: I think it should return i-1 because "i" would already be "after" the max. Second: See my comment to the question. It could give "false up" trend if two adjacend readings are for example 0.5 and 0.7 (I know those would be floats ... it's just to show what I mean) but the actual max of 1.0 is in between those two. In that case, we would be one index off. I don't know if this would matter to OP, but it could happen.

Comment: In my setup, the time between points is so small that it would be insignificant. I actually ended up scraping this process due to the fact that my data was not perfectly consistent, and would fluctuate slightly while generally following a sine trend. Because of this I was getting false readings. Finding the peaks was a step in the process to find the phase shift of 2 sine curves, so I ended up using the cross-correlation method instead, which is much more reliable. For the original problem though, @ispiro 's solution would work. Thank you to everyone for their help, it is greatly appreciated.